# Adding Missing Records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a situation i been working on it since yesterday. but couldnt fix it

```
          Table 1
LN_ID     DATE         CODE
500      01-JUN-2014   00
500      01-MAY-2014   01
500      01-APR-2014   02
500      01-MAR-2014   00
500      01-FEB-2014   04
500      01-JAN-2014   03

501      01-JUN-2014   00
501      01-MAY-2014   01
501      01-APR-2014   02
501      01-MAR-2014   00

502      01-JUN-2014   00
502      01-MAY-2014   01
502      01-APR-2014   02
502      01-MAR-2014   00
502      01-FEB-2014   04
```

this is all one table with each loan of mulitple records.

Loan 500 have 6 records from Jun to Jan and

Loan 501 have only 4 records from Jun to MAR and

Loan 502 have only 5 records from Jun to FEB

I want to insert missing records JUN to JAN for all loan. and want to make code as XX
i want to see this table like this one;

```
          Table 1 (needed)
LN_ID     DATE         CODE
500      01-JUN-2014   00
500      01-MAY-2014   01
500      01-APR-2014   02
500      01-MAR-2014   00
500      01-FEB-2014   04
500      01-JAN-2014   03

501      01-JUN-2014   00
501      01-MAY-2014   01
501      01-APR-2014   02
501      01-MAR-2014   00
501      01-FEB-2014   XX
501      01-JAN-2014   XX

502      01-JUN-2014   00
502      01-MAY-2014   01
502      01-APR-2014   02
502      01-MAR-2014   00
502      01-FEB-2014   04
502      01-JAN-2014   XX
```

Comment: Do you have any sql queries that you have tried to use?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the records by doing a `cross join`.  Then you can use `left join` back to the original data to get the codes.

For the data in your question:

```
select l.ln_id, d.date, coalesce(t1.code, 'XX') as code
from (select distinct ln_id from table1) l cross join
     (select distinct date from table1) d left outer join
     table1 t1
     on t1.ln_id = l.ln_id and t1.date = d.date;
```

Note that your query is tagged in a way that suggests both MySQL and Oracle.  The above is standard SQL and will work on both those databases.

Comment: this query will work if we are missing any date in between some where?

Comment: @user3802500 . . . This assumes that all possible dates and all possible ids appear somewhere in the data, but not all combinations of them.

Comment: This query is not working if we are missing some month value in between. Forexample in Table 1 if we are missing April recod it should also put XX instead of that code.

Comment: @user3802500 . . . That wasn't part of the original question, which is the question that I answered.